# Ending editing after everything in UITableView section was deleted

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

My project contains a tableview. This tableview consists of 2 sections. The first section contains a single cell that is not editable. The second section is populated by an array called data.

There is a button that starts editing mode and allows the user to delete content from the second section.

I'm trying to end editing mode when the second section is empty so that i can select the cell in my first section.(aesthetic purposes)

My code looks like this (simplified, not actual code):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    data.remove(at: indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    if(data.count==0) {
        self.tableView.setEditing(false, animated: true)
        self.tableView.selectRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), animated: false, scrollPosition: .top)
    }
```

This leads to all kinds of weird bugs. Which, according to the documentation, is expected:

> You should not call setEditing:animated: within an implementation of this method. If for some reason you must, invoke it after a delay by using the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method.

It works, but I feel like this would be a hacky solution. It is not clear to me why I should not end editing when everything is deleted. Can someone explain this? Or perhaps any alternatives?

Comment: I'm not sure if anyone outside of Apple can tell you why this doesn't work. It seems to be an implementation detail.Why do you not want to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`? After all, that is what Apple recommends.

Comment: `DispatchQueue asyncAfter` is a much better choice than `performSelector....`.